# Display data from List<string> to asp:repeater with some step

Tags: c#, asp.net

everyone!

I'm new in ASP.net dev, and I'v faced with next problem

I need to display data from List to ASP.Net page with asp:repeater with step i=i+3, but i can't use index with Container.Dataitem and repeaterId.Items.Count always is 0

I need something like that:

```
        <itemtemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                i
            </td>
            <td>
                i+1
            </td>
            <td>
                i+2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </itemtemplate>
```

All data is type of string. I hope, that someone help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

test this:

HTML(.aspx) FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {font: 8pt tahoma;}
        table {border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:5px;}
            table td {border:solid 1px #14c739;padding:5px}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt_demo">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td>
                    <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>- <%# Container.DataItem  %>
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </tr></table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind File

```
List<String> lst_Demo = new List<string>();
lst_Demo.Add("No.1");
lst_Demo.Add("No.2");
lst_Demo.Add("No.3");
lst_Demo.Add("No.4");
lst_Demo.Add("No.5");
lst_Demo.Add("No.6");
lst_Demo.Add("No.7");
lst_Demo.Add("No.8");
rpt_demo.DataSource = lst_Demo;
rpt_demo.DataBind();
```